# How to stop rendering template base on conditions in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Is there a way in Meteor to stop rendering template in some case? I found that this works:

```
Template.test.created = function () {
    if (/* conditions */) {
        this.view.template.renderFunction = function () {
            return null;
        };
    }
};
```

But... maybe anyone can do this better?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to accomplish this within the template/helpers itself.

```
<template name="sometimesVisible">
  {{#if visible}}
    <!-- content here -->
  {{/if}}
</template>

Template.sometimesVisible.helpers({
  visible: function() {
    // conditions here
  }
]);
```

Comment: I want this logic only in JS, without {{#if}} wrapping whole content.

Comment: Why does what I suggested not work for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Best of luck finding a different solution that does the same exact thing for seemingly no reason.